# TCSH: I want to display command output and redirect to a file

Tags: io-redirection, tcsh

I looked at the TSCH man page, which said "Either output-file or error-file may be '/dev/tty' to send output to the terminal." So if I can redirect to two different locations, that would work. But calling, say,

`(make foo > /dev/tty) > error.txt` leaves me with an empty `error.txt`. As does `make foo | tee error.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
 (command > stdout) >& stderr
```

E.g.:

```
 (make foo > /dev/tty) >& error.txt
```

The first `>` redirects the stdout to the tty, then the `>&` redirects whatever's left into error.txt.

In your case, it'd go like this:

```
~> (make foo > /dev/tty) >& error.txt
~> cat error.txt
make: *** No rule to make target `foo'.  Stop.
```

If you want to *both* display it, *and* write it to a file, `|&` is analogous to `>&`, i.e.:

```
~> ( python err.py > /dev/tty ) |& tee error.txt
This is stdout
This is stderr
~> cat error.txt
This is stderr
```